# Ghostscript works on testing environment but not after deployment on Cloud Functions

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Good afternoon,

The following code works like a charm on testing environment (Test Function mode) when creating a new function on Cloud Functions:

```
cmd = f'gs -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=png16m -r600 -sOutputFile="{output_filepath}" {input_filepath}'.split(' ')

process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

But after deployed it gives the following error:

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs'

When I run `subprocess.check_call(['gs', '--version'])` on testing environment it returns the version of Ghostscript, when I run after deployment it gives the same Errno 2.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Almost certainly Ghostscript is not installed, or the directory containing it is not in the $PATH environment variable. Removed the ghostscript tag since I don't believe this is a Ghostscript issue.